# Books Stock using linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have an assignment to write a java program for a books stock using Linkedlist, i have to load books details from txt file, add books manually from scanner, search the linked list for a book using title,part of the title, or author, and display this linked list once not sorted and once sorted by title(I tried to sort it using compareTo and collections.sort(books) but seems that sort does not work for own implemented Linked list).

I have done almost everything, but load method has errors in reading from the file,and display does not display anything.So, everything have errors.

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Stock {
    private LinkedList<Book> books;
    public Stock(){
      books=new LinkedList<>();
    }
    public void Load(File file) throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner scan =new Scanner(file);
        String s=scan.nextLine().trim();
        scan.useDelimiter(":");
        String author, title,edition, publisher;
        int price, quantity;
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            author=scan.next();
            title=scan.next();
            edition=scan.next();
            publisher=scan.next();
            price=scan.nextInt();
            quantity=scan.nextInt();
            books.add(new    Book(author,title,edition,publisher,price,quantity),books.getSize()+1);

        }
    }
    public void purchase(Book book){
        Node<Book> current=books.getfirst();
        for(int i=0; i<books.getSize(); i++){
            if(current.element.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(book.getTitle()))
                current.element.setQuantity(current.element.getQuantity()+book.getQuantity());
            else 
                            books.add(new Book(book), books.getSize()+1);
            current=current.next;

        }

    }
    public void sale(Book book){
        Node<Book> current= books.getfirst();
        for(int i=0; i<books.getSize(); i++){
            if(current.element.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(book.getTitle())){
                if(current.element.getQuantity()>1)
                    current.element.setQuantity(current.element.getQuantity()-1);
                else
                    System.out.print("\n There is NO Copies of this book"+book.getTitle()+"in the stock");
                }
            else System.out.print("\n the book is NOT in the stock");
            current=current.next;
            }
        }
    public boolean search(String s){
        Node<Book> current = books.getfirst();
        for(int i=0; i<books.getSize(); i++){
            if(current.element.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(s))
                return true;
            else if(current.element.getAuthor().equalsIgnoreCase(s))
                return true;
            else {
                for(int y=0; y<current.element.getTitle().length()-s.length()+1; y++){
                    if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(current.element.getTitle().substring(y, y+s.length())))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void Display(){
        Node<Book> current =books.getfirst();
        for(int i=0; i<books.getSize();i++){
            System.out.print("\n "+ current.element.toString());
            current=current.next;
        }
    }
    public void sortedReport(){
        //Collections.sort(books);
        Node<Book> current= books.getfirst();
        for(int i=0; i<books.getSize(); i++){
            System.out.print("\n "+current.element.toString());
            current= current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: follow this link http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/linkedlist/sort-comparator/

Comment: Not sure what is your intention here :  books.add(new    Book(author,title,edition,publisher,price,quantity),books.getSize()+1);

Comment: it add a new Book to LinkedList<Books> in the position books.getSize()+1

Comment: Side note on code quality: **please please please** always use  { braces } around your if {then} else { else} stuff. Or to be precise: for any block, loop, for, whatever: use braces. It is so easy to miss a ; somewhere; and all of a sudden your "correct" code does something completely strange ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out and adjust to your needs.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Stock {
private LinkedList<Book> books;
public Stock(){
  books=new LinkedList<>();
}

public static void main(String a[]){ 
    Stock myStock = new Stock();
    myStock.loadBookDetails ();
    System.out.println("Unsorted list entries: ");
    for(Book b:myStock.books){
        System.out.println(b);
    }
    Collections.sort(myStock.books,new MyTitleComp());
    System.out.println("Sorted list entries: ");
    for(Book b:myStock.books){
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
public void loadBookDetails (){
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\manna\\desktop\\testing.txt")))
        {
            String currentLine;
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[]details = currentLine.split(":");
                books.add(new Book(details[0],details[1],details[2],details[3],Integer.parseInt(details[4]),Integer.parseInt(details[5])));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } 
 }

 }

 class MyPriceComp implements Comparator<Book>{

@Override
public int compare(Book book1, Book book2) {
    if( book1.getPrice()< book2.getPrice()){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
 }
 }

 class MyTitleComp implements Comparator<Book>{

 @Override
 public int compare(Book book1, Book book2) {
    return book1.getTitle().compareToIgnoreCase(book2.getTitle());
}
}

class Book{

private String author, title,edition, publisher;
private int price, quantity;

public Book(String author, String title, String edition, String publisher, int price, int quantity) {
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.edition = edition;
    this.publisher = publisher;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getEdition() {
    return edition;
}

public void setEdition(String edition) {
    this.edition = edition;
}

public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}

public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Book{" + "author=" + author + ", title=" + title + ", edition=" + edition + ", publisher=" + publisher + ", price=" + price + ", quantity=" + quantity + '}';
}


}
```

testing.txt

```
john:earth:e2:p2:12:15
tom:sky:e3:p3:15:24
jane:air:e1:p3:12:31
tina:fire:e5:p6:2:23
```

Comment: I appreciate wasting  you time for  my assignment . sort does not really work , books need to be sorted alphabetically, but  I does not.

Comment: did you try it with my testing.text or your own input? show me examples of input and describe please what does not work

Comment: I tried with another testing file, the file had spaces and another issues. Now it works well.thank you

Comment: How can I use Collection.sort with my own implemented linked list(has only getfirst,getlast, removefirst,removelast, remove,add,addfirst,addlast).

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (new FileReader(file));
```

Try that, since I assume your file is a character file (text file).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use my own implemented LinkedList.

```
public class LinkedList<O> {
private Node<O> first,last;
private int count;
public LinkedList(){}

public Node getfirst(){
    if(first==null) return null;
    else return first;
}
public Node getLast(){
    if(first==null) return null;
    else return last;
}
public int getSize(){
    return count;
}
public void addFirst(Object x){
    if(first==null)first=last=new Node(x);
    else{
        Node temp =new Node(x);
        temp.next=first;
        first=temp;
    }
    count++;
}
public void addLast(Object x){
    if(first==null)first=last=new Node(x);
    else{
        last.next= new Node(x);
        last=last.next;
    }
    count++;
}
public void add(Object x,int index){
    if(index==0)addFirst(x);
    else if(index>=getSize())addLast(x);
    else{
        Node current=first;
        for(int i=0; i<index-1;i++)
            current=current.next;
        Node temp = new Node(x);
        temp.next=current.next;
        current.next=temp;
        count++;
    }
}
public boolean removeFirst(){
    if(first==null)return false;
    else if(first==last){
        first=last=null;
        count--;
        return true;
        }
    else{
        first=first.next;
        count--;
        return true;
        }
}
public boolean removeLast(){
    if(first==null)return false;
    else if(first==last){
        first=last=null;
        count--;
        return true;
        }
    else{
        Node current=first;
        for(int i=0;i<getSize()-2;i++)
            current=current.next;
        last=current;
        last.next=null;
        count--;
        return true;
        }
}
public boolean remove(int index){
    if(index==0)return removeFirst();
    else if(index==getSize()-1)return removeLast();
    else{
        Node current=first;
        for(int i=0;i<index-1;i++)
            current=current.next;
        current.next=(current.next).next;
        count--;
        return true;
          }
  }
```

}

```
public class Node<E> {
   E element;
   Node<E> next;
   public Node(E element) {
      this.element = element;
    }
}
```

when I used :

```
 for(Book b:books){
        System.out.println(b);
 }
```

it gave me an error: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

So, I tried to use :

```
  for(Node<Book> current=books.getfirst(); current !=null; current=current.next){
            System.out.println(current);
        }
```

It print :

```
project11.Node@139a55
project11.Node@1db9742
project11.Node@106d69c
```

collection.sort gave me: The method sort(List, Comparator) in the type Collections is not
applicable for the arguments (LinkedList, Stock.MyTitleComp)

Comment: Every class in java has toString() method in it by default, which is called by System.out.println() if you pass some object of a class to it. When you try to print object of a class, the System.out.println() method will call toString() of the class which returns the className@hashcode of that object. // Class @ followed by hashcode of object in Hexadecimal 
In your case : Node@139a55 ..
You can override the toString method of a class to get different output. See example in my Book class and just do the same in your Node class

Comment: The second err looks like you are trying to call sort with the arg List<Book>. check out and change to LinkedList<Book>